# hibernate - choose a specific column from a join table

Tags: hibernate

I am running an hql, with a right join:

```
select sum(banks.money) from banks right join banks.account where banks.account = :account and (banks.date < :date or banks.date is null) group by banks.account, banks.date
```

hibernate translates it to something like that:

```
select sum(banks.money) from banks right join accounts on banks.account_id = accounts.account_id where banks.account_id = someId and (banks.date < someDate or banks.date is null) ....
```

I want hibernate to take the account_id field from the accounts table, (where I can have an account that is not in the banks table) and not from the banks table.

Is there any way of explicitly tell hibernate on which column of the join table to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting helps...  Anyway...

```
select sum(banks.money) 
from banks 
    right join banks.account acct 
where acct = :account 
  and (banks.date < :date or banks.date is null) 
group by banks.account, banks.date
```

Though personally, I would add it to the join condition:

```
select sum(banks.money) 
from banks 
    right join banks.account acct 
        with acct.id = :accountId
where banks.date < :date 
   or banks.date is null
group by banks.account, banks.date
```

in both cases, specifically note the alias given to the joined association and its use as the qualifier